# W10 settings language won't change

Tags: windows-10, language

One computer on Windows 10 does not completely change language even though everything is configured correctly. The PC correctly changes language except for the settings of Windows 10 who remain in the default language.

I have already changed the language on several PCs and have never had any problems.
Language should be `fr-BE` and not `nl-BE`.

[image: language settings]

[image: Windows settings]

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WinSystemLocale

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
2060             fr-BE            French (Belgium)


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Culture

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
2060             fr-BE            French (Belgium)
```

Comment: Please run `Get-WinSystemLocale` & `Get-Culture`, then update your question with the outputs. Also, are they using the same edition of Windows?

Comment: @spikey_richie done and yes.

Comment: Not sure who flagged to close this due to lacking clarity, but it'd be useful if you added a comment as to why.

Comment: I found that language pack are getting an error 0x800F0954 when downloading.

Comment: @xarj - That indicates system corruption.  What version you f Windows 10 are you running?  Can you run the appropriate DISM and SFC commands to check and repair system corruption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I installed .NET Framework 3.5 which caused the error and run an `sfc /scannow`

Now language packs are downloaded successfully